# How to remove Server Endpoint of "Azure File Sync" that has no VM instance (server)

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

When deleting Azure File Sync resource, Microsoft recommended to remove the Server End Point first. But I didn't read that page at that time. So I deleted my VM first and then I tried to delete the File Sync resource but it didn't work because there was no online server.

**The error message:**

> Endpoint: 'FILESYNC'
>   code: MgmtServerJobExpired
>   detail : Server job with command name DeleteServerEndpoint and id 120efd5a-178c-4b93-8a1c-484b0bb063cd expired.
>   상관 관계 ID: 3896a4c7-f49c-4b67-92a9-963b3e3a7fc3
>   요청 ID: 6313bbba-e2ff-4250-8f76-2cb4d66a34d0

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Server Endpoints cannot be removed when the server is no longer available. The best and simplest way to clean up is to go to the "Registered servers" blade in your Storage Sync Service, select the server that is the VM you deleted (state should show: "Appears Offline") and hit "Unregister".

Server un-registration breaks the trust relationship between server and cloud and as a consequence all Server Endpoints this server might still have in different Sync Groups get cleaned up as well. One stop shop. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

You have to unregister servers first before you will be able to delete Azure File Sync:

Go into STORAGE SYNC SERVICES

- Click on the Sync Service in question
- Click REGISTERED SERVERS
- Click on the server you want to remove
- Click UNREGISTER SERVER
- Type in the (copy / paste) the name of the server in the confirmation box at the bottom

tip from:
https://www.urtech.ca/2019/02/solved-how-to-deregister-a-server-endpoint-from-azure-storage-sync/